# connecting to mac from windows

Tags: osx-lion, remote-desktop, vnc

I have a 11" macbook running Lion that I routinely need to connect remotely from another windows machine. I have been using vnc client on Windows via Lion's screen sharing but the screen size is too small and doesn't seem to be adjustable. Anyone know of a better solution? I wasn't able to compile vncserver's source code on Lion and I haven't been able to find a replacement for screen sharing.

Comment: This is off-topic, but I liked [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com). It's cross-platform and free for personal use.

Comment: +1 for teamviewer. works a treat - can access your remote computers using the desktop software or their web-interface. But best of all, you can initiate file transfers which is really handy

Answer (score 1):

No need to compile VNC Server.  Go to Sharing in System Preferences, enable Remote Management, click Computer Settings, check box to enable VNC and enter a password that will be required to authenticate connection.

Comment: +1 for using the tools that are already available.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/UK/).. It's free and works well on Mac. :)